# Finding out percentage of null values when grouped by a particular column using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Below is a small snapshot of my dataframe:

```
avg_rating_of_driver    avg_rating_by_driver    bins
0   4.7 5.0 (3, 125]
1   5.0 5.0 NaN
2   4.3 5.0 (2, 3]
3   4.6 4.9 (3, 125]
4   4.4 4.9 (3, 125]
5   3.5 5.0 (1, 2]
6   NaN 4.0 (0, 1]
7   5.0 5.0 (1, 2]
8   4.5 5.0 (1, 2]
9   NaN 5.0 (0, 1]
10  5.0 4.9 (0, 1]
11  4.0 5.0 (2, 3]
12  NaN 5.0 (0, 1]
13  4.0 5.0 NaN
14  NaN 5.0 (0, 1]
15  NaN 5.0 (0, 1]
16  5.0 3.0 (0, 1]
17  3.9 4.8 NaN
18  4.6 4.8 (3, 125]
19  5.0 5.0 NaN
20  NaN 3.0 (0, 1]
21  NaN 5.0 (0, 1]
22  NaN 5.0 NaN
23  5.0 5.0 NaN
24  4.5 4.7 (3, 125]
25  NaN 5.0 (0, 1]
```

The bins have following values:

```
 (0,1] (1,2] (2,3] (3,125]
```

I am interested in **grouping by bins** and finding out **percent of null values** in each bin.

This means when grouped by **bins** how many percent columns have **NA values** for that row.

Comment: Could you provide a simple/small working example of the dataframe? What if the bin itself has `NaN` value?

Comment: You are right. Many bins do have null values.

Comment: Okay..provided a reduced dataframe with only a couple of columns

Comment: @optimus_prime, did Mahdi's answer answered your question? If it did then please don't forget to accept it, if it didn't please provide an expected output

Comment: Just did. Sorry. got caught up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
dg = df.groupby('bins')
for col in df.columns:
    if col!='bins':  
       print (dg[col].apply(pd.isnull).mean())
```

Since `dg[col].apply(pd.isnull)` is an array of 1's and 0', its mean is equal to the sum of all 1's devided by total number, a.k.a percentage of  `NaN` values!

You can also write it with no `for` loop:

```
dg.apply(pd.isnull).mean()
```

but this case returns a row with zero value for `bins`, as well.